# How to use scalax.io.CommandLineParser?

Tags: command-line, scala

I want to create a class that takes string array as a constructor argument and has command line option values as members vals. Something like below, but I don't understand how the Bistate works.

```
import scalax.data._
import scalax.io.CommandLineParser

class TestCLI(arguments: Array[String]) extends CommandLineParser {
    private val opt1Option = new Flag("p", "print") with AllowAll
    private val opt2Option = new Flag("o", "out") with AllowAll
    private val strOption = new StringOption("v", "value") with AllowAll
    private val result = parse(arguments)
    // true or false
    val opt1 = result(opt1Option)
    val opt2 = result(opt2Option)
    val str = result(strOption)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are shorter alternatives to that pattern matching to get a boolean:

```
val opt1 = result(opt1Option).isInstanceOf[Positive[_]]
val opt2 = result(opt2Option).posValue.isDefined
```

The second one is probably better. The field **posValue** is an Option (there's **negValue** as well). The method **isDefined** from Option tells you whether it is a Some(x) or None.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not personally familiar with Scalax or `Bistate` in particular, but just looking at the scaladocs, it looks like a left-right disjunction.  Scala's main library has a monad very much like this (`Either`), so I'm surprised that they didn't just use the standard one.

In essence, `Bistate` and `Either` are a bit like `Option`, except their "`None`-equivalent" can contain a value.  For example, if I were writing code using `Either`, I might do something like this:

```
def div(a: Int, b: Int) = if (b != 0) Left(a / b) else Right("Divide by zero")

div(4, 2) match {
  case Left(x) => println("Result: " + x)
  case Right(e) => Println("Error: " + e)
}
```

This would print "`Result: 2`".  In this case, we're using `Either` to simulate an exception.  We return an instance of `Left` which contains the value we want, unless that value cannot be computed for some reason, in which case we return an error message wrapped up inside an instance of `Right`.

Answer (score 0):

So if I want to assign to variable boolean value of whether flag is found I have to do like below?

```
val opt1 = result(opt1Option) match {
    case Positive(_) => true
    case Negative(_) => false
}
```

Isn't there a way to write this common case with less code than that?